# Microsoft Graph People API returns a 404 despite consented permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When using the Microsoft Graph API endpoint `/v1.0/me/people` I'm presented with a 404 error despite consented with People.Read and People.Read.All permissions. I've added the response object and a screenshot of Graph Explorer below. Any suggestions on how to get a 200 OK instead? An empty array would be sufficient for me.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-04-24T07:09:23",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I'm experiencing this error on a Azure AD tenant I created for testing purposes with only two user objects and two groups. There are no Microsoft 365 services connected to this tenant. Judging by the [People API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/people-example) I can imagine this might have something to do with the 404 error, although I couldn't find it clearly specified that Microsoft 365 licenses are a requirement for the People API. It's good to note that other endpoints such as `/v1.0/users` and `/v1.0/groups` work.

[image: Screenshot from Graph Explorer]

Comment: Check if the user has Exchange License or not.

Comment: No users in this tenant have Exchange licenses. Is an Exchange license a requirement for the People API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, To use the people API you need to have exchange license as all the people details are stored in Exchange.

You are able to get User and Group details because they are coming from Directory Services(Azure Active Directory) workload .

Comment: Good to know, thanks for clarifying! Do you know where I can find this in the Microsoft docs, because I'm curious to know if there are other requirements I should be aware of.

Comment: I didn't get any document saying this but you can check the underlying API using `/v1.0/me/people?$whatif`.